# Real Time Detection of Multiple Objects with Various Classes with YOLO

Tags: opencv, object-detection, yolo

I am currently working on detecting whether motorbike drivers are wearing a helmet or not using YoloV3. Firstly I am using the coco model to detect motorbike and then sending the detected motorbike image to the helmet detection Yolo model.
Currently, Yolov3 is taking lots of time in loading weights and performing the detection for each frame.
Is there any way to reduce this time taken as I need to perform the detections in real time.
Also, should I go for multiple Yolo models or should I train a single model containing both the motorbike and helmet class?

Comment: Without GPU it runs at about 3fps on my laptop. You mentioned that it's taking a lot of time loading weights, are you reloading the network for each image? If you're getting less than 1 fps check to make sure that you're not recreating the network every time.

Comment: Hey. The network is not created every time. Most of the time taken by model is in forwarding part.
`layerOutputs = config_data[0].forward(config_data[1])`
Is there a way to reduce it ?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have two different questions:

1. Is there any way to reduce this time taken as I need to perform the
   detections in real time?
2. Should I go for multiple Yolo models or should I train a single
   model containing both the motorbike and helmet class?

Q1: YOLO should work in real-time with GPU unless the image resolution is enormous or your hardware does not meet the requirements. If you can not change the two things above,

Try the smaller model, yolov3_tiny for example. From PyTorch Hub;

```
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov3', 'yolov3_tiny')
```

Q2: Single model, since YOLO is capable of object detection with multiple classes without sacrificing much speed and accuracy.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the answer. Just had one doubt, is Yolo_tiny less accurate than Yolo?

Comment: Hey! Np. Yes. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/01/27/yolo-and-tiny-yolo-object-detection-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-movidius-ncs/